# grails version update from 3.1.11 to 3.1.16

Tags: serialization, gradle, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails3

I have a grails 3.1.16 application. In that i'm using some plugins of grails 3.1.11.  When i'm running my application with **grails run-app** command its working fine.But when i make the war file and deploy it to tomcat it is picking wrong version of some files.

Initially my app is in grails 3.1.11. But i need some improvements that are done in 3.1.16(**BeforeValidateHelper implements serializable**). So i have updated the version my grails-app to 3.1.16. .But my plugins are made in 3.1.11 version.  When i'm running **grails run-app** its working fine(BeforeValidateHelper implemented  serializable). But when i'm deplying it as war file to tomcat, its showing BeforeValidateHelper is not serializable.

when i open **http://localhost:8080** its showing grails 3.1.16 version(which is correct).
But its picking files of grails 3.1.11(BeforeValidateHelper)

Comment: Check dependency-report to see which plugin requires the old library and exclude the dependency using: 
compile("the:plugin:version"){
        exclude module:'bla'
    }

Comment: I have checked gradle dependency graph.No where i could find old jar reference.

Comment: Check the jar where the class is loaded from 
Something like: 
def c = BeforeValidateHelper.class
println c.getResource("/${c.name.replace('.','/')}.class")